# Help Text for required fields like name or can we apply validation rule for that

Tags: apex, fields, helptext

Without using customisation, can we give any help text in name field of object?

Comment: Can you add some more detail about what you are trying to achieve? It's hard to tell what your actual question is as written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "bzzzzzt" (No).  Boy would I like to see this. There is an [Idea to vote up](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000ISqDAAW)

Workarounds include:

- Validation rules (users learn through doing/self-cure)
- Defaulting the value using URL hacking or VF pages with a page action method.

Comment: I knew there was an idea there, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: @sfdcfox - the absence of this feature doesn't pass the straight-face test

Comment: The irony was, I had a version of FLH that supported multiple languages and supported all fields standard and custom, links and any manner of random HTML, back when S-Controls were still a thing.